# Função Pesquisar no Visual Studio Code (Ctrl + F)

Tags: visual-studio-code

A função de buscar do VC Code, cso tenh varias ocorrências e o usuário ficar pesquisando, sempre fica em loop. Ao chegar ao fim da página, se o usuário avançar com a pesquisa retorna ao inicio e fica sempre rodando.

Teria como fazer ele parar ao fim da página?

Comment: Parar eu não sei, mas no campo de search ele mostra ao lado o número de ocorrências da palavra que vc pesquisou e em qual número vc esta tipo em 5 de 10

Comment: É, observei isso, queria mesmo era por pra ele parar...

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A opção de para o Search na última ocorrência evitando o Loop ainda não foi implementada. Na verdade essa opção é tratada com `feature-request` e foi adicionada na lista de pedidos em 11 de Agosto de 2017

```
Stop find operation at last match of the file #28666
```

Uma dica é que vc pode usar a tecla <kbd>F3</kbd> para ir pulando de ocorrência para ocorrência *(mas o looping vai continuar...)*

Link desse Issue no GitHub oficial: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28666